Is there a way to skip the signin page using latest NextJs and Auth.js
I am new to NextJs (14) and have been trying to get it working with the AuthJs (v5). I would like to achieve the scenario, whereby if the user is not logged in and redirected to the signin page. They are then immediately sent on to a provider, without requiring them to click a button
I have successfully configured a number of providers and have been able to login to my application, using the OTB signin page, creating a custom signin page (and having middleware redirect to it) and also creating a component form (containing a button).
import { auth, signIn } from "auth"
 
export default function SignInButtonDuendeButton() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        "use server"
        await signIn("duende-identity-server6")
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Signin with DuendeIDS6Provider</button>
    </form>
  )
}

In all of these situations, the user needs to click a button in order to begin the journey to the sub provider.
I have tried a variety of approachs callng signIn("duende-identity-server6") from a range of places, but it always fails often with execptions relating to 'cookies can only be modified in a server action'.
I am unsure how to correctly call a server action immediately on page load? I have also seen a number of examples on the web that use 'useEffect'. But it seems to be an older approach, not compatible with the latest versions of NextJs. (Example: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4078)
Any suggestions on how to immediately redirect to a sub provider would be greatly appreciated.

Did you find a solution?

unfortunately I did not

This approach worked for me with Keycloak: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4078#discussioncomment-9806999
My versions:

next@14.2.6
next-auth@5.0.0-beta.20

In your case, it might be like this.
// auth.ts

NextAuth({
    pages: {
      signIn: "/api/auth",
    },
    // ... rest of your config
  })

// app/api/auth/route.ts

import { signIn } from "@/auth";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const searchParams = new URL(req.url).searchParams;
  return signIn("duende-identity-server6", { redirectTo: searchParams.get("callbackUrl") ?? "" });
}

Note that you still need the app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts file.
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import { handlers } from "@/auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

Hope this helps and works for you too!
